# How to open you tube video playlist in custom listview in android

Tags: android, youtube

Is there any way to open you tube video play list in our custom list view and when user clicks on any video inside our custom list view then it should play.

Please tell me if there is any way . I have checked you tube API

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: I am also looking answer for same question..Do u got any solution ,If yes the please answer it below I will vote up .I need it badly

Comment: Yes I have implemented it . I will share the code with you

Comment: Okay Sure I will it to you

Comment: If there is no personal or patented stuffs, can you guys please share source code in the answer of this question, then I and other people can get it? Because I wasted lots of time but can't find the answer.